# Avoid display duplicate elements in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates, display

So I saved some data in localStorage.

I get them back from localstorage to the table.

When I click on the button to enter new data, the data entered earlier is duplicated in the table. When I refresh the page, everything is fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function save() {

    list.forEach(function(item) {

      var nameNode = document.createTextNode(item.name);
      var surnameNode = document.createTextNode(item.surname);
      var dataNode = document.createTextNode(item.data);
      var nrNode = document.createTextNode(item.nr);

      var tdName = document.createElement("td");
      var tdSurname = document.createElement("td");
      var tdData = document.createElement("td");
      var tdNr = document.createElement("td");

      tdName.appendChild(nameNode);
      tdSurname.appendChild(surnameNode);
      tdData.appendChild(dataNode);
      tdNr.appendChild(nrNode);

      var tr = document.createElement("tr");

      tr.appendChild(tdName);
      tr.appendChild(tdSurname);
      tr.appendChild(tdData);
      tr.appendChild(tdNr);
      // download table and insert cells and rows
      var table = document.getElementById("table");
      table.appendChild(tr);

    });
  }

  list = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("osoba") === null ? [] : localStorage.getItem("osoba"));
  save();

  $("#send").click(function() {

    var osoba = {};
    osoba["name"] = document.getElementById("name").value;
    osoba["surname"] = document.getElementById("subname").value;
    osoba["data"] = document.getElementById("date_bth").value;
    osoba["nr"] = document.getElementById("numer_phone").value;

    list.push(osoba);

    localStorage.setItem("osoba", JSON.stringify(list));
    document.getElementById("name").value = "";
    document.getElementById("surname").value = "";
    document.getElementById("date_bth").value = "";
    document.getElementById("numer_phone").value = "";
    save();
  });
});
```

How to avoid duplication in the table without reloading the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save, you need to first clear the data already on the table or it will be added to it again when you call save. Here's how you do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function save() {
        $("#table tr").remove(); // <- this

        list.forEach(function (item) {

            var nameNode = document.createTextNode(item.name);
            var surnameNode = document.createTextNode(item.surname);
            var dataNode = document.createTextNode(item.data);
            var nrNode = document.createTextNode(item.nr);

            var tdName = document.createElement("td");
            var tdSurname = document.createElement("td");
            var tdData = document.createElement("td");
            var tdNr = document.createElement("td");

            tdName.appendChild(nameNode);
            tdSurname.appendChild(surnameNode);
            tdData.appendChild(dataNode);
            tdNr.appendChild(nrNode);

            var tr =document.createElement("tr");

            tr.appendChild(tdName);
            tr.appendChild(tdSurname);
            tr.appendChild(tdData);
            tr.appendChild(tdNr);

            // download table and insert cells and rows
            var table = document.getElementById("table");
            table.appendChild(tr);

        });
    }

    list = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("osoba") === null ? [] : localStorage.getItem("osoba"));
    save();

    $("#send").click(function(){

        var osoba = {};
        osoba["name"] = document.getElementById("name").value;
        osoba["surname"] = document.getElementById("subname").value;
        osoba["data"] = document.getElementById("date_bth").value;
        osoba["nr"] = document.getElementById("numer_phone").value;

        list.push(osoba);

        localStorage.setItem("osoba",JSON.stringify(list));
        document.getElementById("name").value="";
        document.getElementById("surname").value="";
        document.getElementById("date_bth").value="";
        document.getElementById("numer_phone").value="";
        save();
    });
});
```